# Using Selenium to find elements with variable IDs

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use Selenium to scrape some data from a website. Unfortunately the IDs of elements is variable.

An example id is: 
`<li id="ember1118" class="ember-view"><script id="metamorph-55-start">`, where emberXXXX is variable.

Is there a way to use find_element_by_xpath? For example, within the above element is the following:

```
<a data-ember-action="19" title="Rugby League " class="" data-bindattr-20="20">
```

How would I address this element using the static title "Rugby League"?

Using Chrome's inspect to Copy>XPath gives:  "//*[@id="ember1118"]/a" which is dependent on the variable ID. I'm quite new to this so if any more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: This may work for you `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Rugby League ']")` additional info using xpath can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following XPATH:

```
  "//li[contains(@id,'ember')]//a[@title='Rugby League ']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I believe there is a type in your Xpath (missing parenthesis around (@id,'ember')). Adding in the parenthesis fixed my problem. 

Cheers.